# How to say it when you can't be present due to some reason

Tags: phrases

In Western countries, can you call your teacher or boss to tell them that you'll be absent due to some reason; for example, you need to take care of your sick child, or you need to attend a very important wedding, or you need to fix an emergency at home: your water pipe is broken.

If yes, what do you name this act?

Is there a similar phrase like "call in sick"?

Boss said to an employee: You've (xxx) three times in the last month.

Comment: A wedding is hardly an emergency - you should have booked leave for it weeks ago! I don't think there is a general expression for requesting time off in an emergency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the U.S., the employee is often said to be taking a "personal day". The boss would say, "You've taken three personal days in the last month." Different workplaces might use different terms ("personal leave", etc.).